# ServiceWorkers and Next.js: How would one integrate Service workers in production with a next.js app?

Tags: caching, next.js, service-worker

I am working with `"next": "^9.3.2"` and integrated a service worker (including this just in case someone else has a similar question):

File structure:

```
pages
public
  static
  serviceWorker.js
server
  index.js
```

In `server/index.js`

```
 async function start() {
   const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
   const app = nextJS({ dev });
   const server = express();
   
   ....
    server.get('/serviceWorker.js', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public', 'serviceWorker.js'));
   });

   /* later */

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
       server.use(express.static('.next/static'));
       server.get('/service-worker.js', (req, res) => {
       res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'serviceWorker.js'));
    });
```

In `public/serviceWorker.js`

var currentCaches = {
css: 'CSS',
images: 'images'
};

```
const cacheFiles = {
  css: [
    // 'http://localhost:8016/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/styles/styles.css',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css'
  ],
  images: [
    // 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
    // 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
    // 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/public/static/media/search@2x.png',
    // 'http://localhost:8016/public/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg'
  ]
};

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.log('Hello world from the Service Worker ');
  event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all([
      caches.open(currentCaches.css).then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll(cacheFiles.css);
      }),
      caches.open(currentCaches.images).then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll(cacheFiles.images);
      })
    ])
  );
});
```

Right now I am declaring the `css` paths in that object above* like I would in my _app.js file:

```
    import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
    import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
    
    import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
    import 'esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css';
    
    import '../styles/styles.scss';
    import 'leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css';
```

- Figure this would apply to the images too

So my question is since next.js spits out a `static/css` on a production build:

```
   .next
     cache
     server
     static
        chunks
        css < ----- 
         476a94f2.d9a9e468.chunk.css
         dbd51271.19268786.chunk.css
         styles.9ca4e15c.chunk.css
```

How would one specifically have the serviceWorker know what these file names would be (as well as images, fonts, svg's etc)? As i'm assuming the numbers are to help with caching!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you need some way of integrating with your web app's build process if you want to get a list of hashed URLs for use within your service worker.

Given that you're using Next.js, a plugin like [`next-offline`](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline) can help by doing two things:

- Integrating with your build process to get a list of your hashed URLs.
- Generating the entirety of your service worker for you, using [`workbox-precaching`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching) under the hood to ensure that your URLs are properly cached and kept up to date.

You can implement something similar yourself if you'd prefer not to use `next-offline`, but you'd need to use something like [`next-assets-manifest`](https://github.com/webdeveric/next-assets-manifest) to obtain the list of hashed URLs, write your own service worker, and figure out how to inject those URLs into the service worker.

Comment: Thanks so much Jeff! I'll look into it. Think initially being excited about serviceWorkers.js and what they can do, I wanted to start without abstractions, but given what you said I might just try to pay attention to the abstractions so it doesn't feel so magical!